# OpenCV - Recognize a serie of symbols

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to recognize numbers written in a cartoonish font, so the traditional tools (e.g. pytesser) did not really work. However, I was able to get quite accurate single digit recognition with cv2.matchTemplate and a library of the 10 digits. I am basically treating each digit as a symbol and simply trying to find the best match.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def match_char(im1, im2):
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(im1,im2,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    return max_va

def process_image(im, i):
    try:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        a, t = cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
        return t
    except:
        print("Error while processing the image")
        pass

def process_lib(im, i):
    try:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        a, t = cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        return t
    except:
        print("Error while processing the image")
        pass

def process_num():
    test = cv2.imread('test.png')
    test = process_image(test, 11)
    test = cv2.resize(test, (0,0), fx=2.2, fy=2.2) #best
    scores = [] 

    for i in range(10):
        img = cv2.imread('char-{}.png'.format(i))
        img = process_lib(img, i)
        scores.append(match_char(img, test))

    win = scores.index(max(scores))
    print("The best match is {} with {}".format(win, scores[win]))
```

The problem is that I was not able to extend this to multiple digits numbers. Even when generating two digits numbers and trying to match them, the program always identifies a single digit as the best match. If I restrain the search to two digits numbers, it sometimes gets one digit correct, but never both. Of course, this is not the most elegant solution, but it seemed the simplest and even that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a threshold and filter the `cv2.matchTemplate` result below this thresh

I think the following code works for you:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv.imread('image.png')
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv.imread('template.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
cv.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

For more information [see](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)